# How can I reduce the amount of logs generated from my Hadoop Yarn Container?

Tags: hadoop, logging, containers, hadoop-yarn

I am using Hadoop 2.7.3, doing some map reduce using Yarn.
The logs generated for each container is astronomical. The level which is obviously used is DEBUG. 
I would like to increase the log level to INFO.

My installation is more or less the default installation.

I tried modifying the container-log4j.properties in my hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-*.jar as described in https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/98259/hdp-250-how-to-override-default-container-log4j-in.html but this did not help. My stdout files for each containers are huge... and most probably also the reason why my map/reduce are so slow.

Does anyone have an idea how I could increase my log level to INFO in my stdout container log files?

Here is an extract one of my stdout:

> ~/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1501740469795_0001/container_1501740469795_0001_01_000001:1282> more stdout
>   08:08:55.337 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl - JvmMetrics, JVM related metrics etc.
>   08:08:55.348 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterInt org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.metrics.MRAppMetrics.jobsSubmitted with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, sampleName=Ops, always=false, type=DEFAULT,
>    value=[], valueName=Time)
>   08:08:55.355 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterInt org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.metrics.MRAppMetrics.jobsCompleted with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, sampleName=Ops, always=false, type=DEFAULT,
>    value=[], valueName=Time)
>   08:08:55.360 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterInt org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.metrics.MRAppMetrics.jobsFailed with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, sampleName=Ops, always=false, type=DEFAULT, va
>   lue=[], valueName=Time)
>   08:08:55.364 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterInt org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.metrics.MRAppMetrics.jobsKilled with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, sampleName=Ops, always=false, type=DEFAULT, va
>   lue=[], valueName=Time)
>   08:08:55.364 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableGaugeInt org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.metrics.MRAppMetrics.jobsPreparing with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, sampleName=Ops, always=false, type=DEFAULT, v
>   alue=[], valueName=Time)
>   08:08:55.365 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableGaugeInt org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.metrics.MRAppMetrics.jobsRunning with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, sampleName=Ops, always=false, type=DEFAULT, val
>   ue=[], valueName=Time)
>   08:08:55.365 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterInt org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.metrics.MRAppMetrics.mapsLaunched with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, sampleName=Ops, always=false, type=DEFAULT, 
>   value=[], valueName=Time)
>   08:08:55.365 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterInt org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.metrics.MRAppMetrics.mapsCompleted with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, sampleName=Ops, always=false, type=DEFAULT,
>    value=[], valueName=Time)
>   ...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are `mapreduce.map.log.level` and `mapreduce.reduce.log.level` set to in your mapred-site.xml?

Comment: I had not set them. I used the defaults which is INFO for both. Now I tried specifying them in my mapred-site.xml and that does not help its the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was neglecting the WARNING which was sent to stderr.

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/HADOOP_DATA-2.7.3/yarnData/usercache/jj/appcache/application_1501771750571_0001/filecache/11/map-reducer-job.jar/lib/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

I am packing my jobs in a Jar file with its needed libraries in a subdirectory lib. I had included in its lib an extra slf4j binding.

The solution was to remove the second slf4j binding from my job jar file.

After this there was no confusion and the trace level used was the one defined i.e. INFO. !!!

Comment: This actually fixed many side effects, like "unreachable nodes", failing tasks...